# How can create loop for below function

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Here webdriver should click on each element, but the action is same, can you anyone help me 
I am new to JavaScript

```
public void clickOnAllFiters(){
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.scroll-item.all")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.scroll-item.news")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.scroll-item.results")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.scroll-item.schedules")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.scroll-item.images")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.scroll-item.video")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.scroll-item.comment")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.scroll-item.activity")).click();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clickOnAllFilters("div.scroll-item.activity", "div.scroll-item.activity"); // You can add more, or simply send an array of strings.

public void clickOnAllFilters(String... filters)
{
    for(String filter : filters)
    {
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(filter)).click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the strings into an array and loop through the array.

```
String[] strings = new String[] {"div.scroll-item.all", ...};
for (String string : strings) {
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(string)).click();
}
```